# Latest Codility Time Problems

Tags: c#

Just got done with the latest Codility, passed it, but didnt get 100% on it

Here is the spec

A prefix of a string S is any leading contiguous part of S. For example, "c" and "cod" are prefixes of the string "codility". For simplicity, we require prefixes to be non-empty.
The product of prefix P of string S is the number of occurrences of P multiplied by the length of P. More precisely, if prefix P consists of K characters and P occurs exactly T times in S, then the product equals K * T.

For example, S = "abababa" has the following prefixes:

```
"a", whose product equals 1 * 4 = 4,
"ab", whose product equals 2 * 3 = 6,
"aba", whose product equals 3 * 3 = 9,
"abab", whose product equals 4 * 2 = 8,
"ababa", whose product equals 5 * 2 = 10,
"ababab", whose product equals 6 * 1 = 6,
"abababa", whose product equals 7 * 1 = 7.
```

The longest prefix is identical to the original string. The goal is to choose such a prefix as maximizes the value of the product. In above example the maximal product is 10.
In this problem we consider only strings that consist of lower-case English letters (a−z).

So basically, it is a string traverse problem. I was able to pass all the validation parts, but I lost on the time. Here is what I wrote

```
int Solution(string S)
{
     int finalCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= S.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string prefix = S.Substring(0, i + 1);
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= S.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (prefix.Length + j <= S.Length)
                {
                    string newStr = S.Substring(j, prefix.Length);
                    if (newStr == prefix)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (j == S.Length - 1)
                {
                    int product = count * prefix.Length;
                    if (product > finalCount)
                    {
                        finalCount = product;
                    }
                }
            }
         }
           return  finalCount;
}
```

I know that the nested loop is killing me, but I cannot think of a way to traverse the "sections" of the string without adding the other loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the test case that failed?

Comment: I got a 50/100, failing all the Time Tests. The time complexity was O(N ** 2) or O(N ** 3), but it is supposed to be O(N). One of the tests was called large_random_string 
cyclic + random string

Comment: Managed to get 56/100 in about 10 mins but I'm no performance guru, I think your string assignment is affecting it a little bit (your solution looks simple enough to be quite quick). Try using indexing on the substring to compare it against the string instead of creating string instances. Strings are immutable and I reckon you are getting a lot of string objects being instantiated

Comment: What are you getting for times on the first 10 or so? Is it somewhere in the range of 0.30 - 0.37? I slapped it together using recursion and got 56/100 and even failed on a few validations .

Comment: Yea it's in the .3 range. Not sure what to add

Comment: Your code works O(N ** 3) - it's two nested loop and checking strings to be equal every time.

I don't know how to solve this problem in your way in O(n), with traverse. 
I got my 100% with a tricky, but easy solution, using Z-algo. It becomes really easy to solve it, if you find Z-function on string.

Comment: @RustamGaneyev can you post a link with more info?

Comment: @IsaacLevin, http://rustam-kot.blogspot.ru/2013/11/codility-prefix-problem.html

Answer (score 4):

Naive brute-force solution takes O(N ** 3) time. Choose length from 1 to N, get a prefix of its length and count occurences by brute-force searching. Сhoosing length takes O(N) time and brute force takes O(N ** 2) time, totally O(N ** 3). 
If you use KMP or Z-algo, you can find occurences in O(N) time, so the whole solution will be O(N ** 2) time.

And you can precalc occurences, so it will take O(N) + O(N) = O(N) time solution.

```
vector<int> z_function(string &S); //z-function, z[0] = S.length()

vector<int> z = z_function(S);
//cnt[i] - count of i-length prefix occurrences of S
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
  ++cnt[z[i]];

 //if cnt[i] is in S, cnt[i - 1] will be in S
 int previous = 0;
 for (int i = n; i > 0; --i) {
  cnt[i] += previous;
  previous = cnt[i];
 }
```

Here's the [blog post](http://rustam-kot.blogspot.ru/2013/11/codility-prefix-problem.html), explaining all O(N ** 3), O(N ** 2), O(N) solutions.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am a little confused on the initial retrieval of the count. Do you have an algorithm in code for what z_function actually does

Comment: @Isaac Levin, probably [it](http://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/the-z-algorithm/) may help you.

Comment: @IsaacLevin, in two words: z-algo creates an array z, where z[i] denotes for maximum substring starting from i-th index of string, which matches to prefix of string.

Check this link to more:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/zalg.pdf, it is clear explanation how z-algo works

Answer (score 1):

my effort was as follows trying to eliminate unnecessary string compares, i read isaacs blog but it is in c how would this translate to c#, i even went as far as using arrays everywhere to avoid the string immutability factor but there was no improvement

```
        int Rtn = 0;
        int len = S.Length;

        if (len > 1000000000)
            return 1000000000;

        for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++)
        {
            string tofind = S.Substring(0, i);
            int tofindlen = tofind.Length;
            int occurencies = 0;

            for (int ii = 0; ii < len; ii++)
            {
                int found = FastIndexOf(S, tofind.ToCharArray(), ii);
                if (found != -1)
                {
                    if ((found == 0 && tofindlen != 1) || (found >= 0))
                    {
                        ii = found;
                    }
                    ++occurencies ;
                }
            }
            if (occurencies > 0)
            {
                int total = occurencies * tofindlen;

                if (total > Rtn)
                {
                    Rtn = total;
                }
            }
        }
        return Rtn;
    }


    static int FastIndexOf(string source, char[] pattern, int start)
    {

        if (pattern.Length == 0) return 0;
        if (pattern.Length == 1) return source.IndexOf(pattern[0], start);
        bool found;
        int limit = source.Length - pattern.Length + 1 - start;
        if (limit < 1) return -1;

        char c0 = pattern[0];
        char c1 = pattern[1];
        // Find the first occurrence of the first character
        int first = source.IndexOf(c0, start, limit);

        while ((first != -1) && (first + pattern.Length <= source.Length))
        {
            if (source[first + 1] != c1)
            {
                first = source.IndexOf(c0, ++first);
                continue;
            }
            found = true;
             for (int j = 2; j < pattern.Length; j++)
                if (source[first + j] != pattern[j])
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (found) return first;
            first = source.IndexOf(c0, ++first);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: i've tried every possible way of trying this using various methods including boyer moore and i still can't get more then 56/100 and a complexity of O(n**2)

Comment: because N is too large, 10^5. If N was about 10^4, your solution would pass.

Answer (score 0):

I only got a 43... I like my code though! Same script in javascript got 56 for what it's worth.

```
using System;

class Solution
{
    public int solution(string S)
    {

    int highestCount = 0;

    for (var i = S.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int occurs = 0;
        string prefix = S.Substring(0, i);    
        int tempIndex = S.IndexOf(prefix) + 1;             
        string tempString = S;            

        while (tempIndex > 0)
        {
            tempString = tempString.Substring(tempIndex);
            tempIndex = tempString.IndexOf(prefix);                                
            tempIndex++;
            occurs++;                                          
        }

        int product = occurs * prefix.Length;

        if ((product) > highestCount)
        {
            if (highestCount >  1000000000)              
                return 1000000000;                           
            highestCount = product;
        }
    }

    return highestCount;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works better

```
    private int MaxiumValueOfProduct(string input)
    {
        var positions = new List<int>();
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= input.Length; i++)
        {
            var subString = input.Substring(0, i);
            int position = 0;
            while ((position < input.Length) &&
                   (position = input.IndexOf(subString, position, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1)
            {
                positions.Add(position);
                ++position;
            }

            var currentMax = subString.Length * positions.Count;
            if (currentMax > max) max = currentMax;
            positions.Clear();
        }

        return max;
    }
```